# MapBox Reserved Country Code Elements (ISO 3166)

Tags: mapbox, mapbox-gl-js

I'm curious if anybody knows how to colour a specific country that no longer exists (i.e., Soviet Union) using MapBox's built-in function?

```
    map.on('load', function () {
    // Add source for country polygons using the Mapbox Countries tileset
    // The polygons contain an ISO 3166 alpha-3 code which can be used to for joining the data
    // https://docs.mapbox.com/vector-tiles/reference/mapbox-countries-v1
    map.addSource('countries', {
        type: 'vector',
        url: 'mapbox://mapbox.country-boundaries-v1'
    });


    // Add filled county polygons for highlighted display.
    map.addLayer(
        {
            'id': 'countries-highlighted',
            'type': 'fill',
            'source': 'countries',
            'source-layer': 'country_boundaries',
            'paint': {
                'fill-outline-color': '#484896',
                'fill-color': '#6e599f',
                'fill-opacity': 0.75
            },
            // Display a single country 
            'filter': ['in', 'iso_3166_1', 'SU']
        },
        'admin-1-boundary-bg'
    );
```

This works fine for a country like USA (ISO 3166-1: 'US'). However, nothing is displayed for former countries like the Soviet Union (ISO 3166-1: 'SU')

I would appreciate if anyone has accomplished this before or can recommend the optimal procedure.
For example, group all of the current countries that made up the former U.S.S.R. (although the border boundaries may not match perfectly)
Or, if there is a downloadable tileset that includes all former countries.

Comment: I'm trying to create a reproduction of your issue here, can you provide the style you're using? 

https://stackblitz.com/edit/mapbox-simple-map-nzxfrv?file=index.ts

Answer (score 0):

[SU](https://www.iso.org/obp/ui/#iso:code:3166:SU)

> Removed from ISO 3166-1 in 1992 when former USSR was divided into:
> Armenia (AM, ARM, 051), Azerbaijan (AZ, AZE, 031), Estonia (EE, EST,
> 233), Georgia (GE, GEO, 268), Kazakstan (KZ, KAZ, 398), Kyrgyzstan
> (KG, KGZ, 417), Latvia (LV, LVA, 428), Lithuania (LT, LTU, 440),
> Republic of Moldova (MD, MDA, 498), Russian Federation (RU, RUS, 643),
> Tajikistan (TJ, TJK, 762), Turkmenistan (TM, TKM, 795), Uzbekistan
> (UZ, UZB, 860). NOTE: Belarus (BY, BLR, 112) and Ukraine (UA, UKR,
> 804) are not listed because they were separately coded in ISO 3166
> already before the USSR was split.